# Как не вызывать словарь при проверке

Tags: python, словари, проверка

Это макет ситуации в которую, я попал. Независимо от ситуации, при упаминания словаря с функциями, он свершает все записанные в него функции. Ккак не выводить весь словарь и вызывать его в его ветке?

```
con = True

def p(k , a):
print (k,' ', a)


dic = ({
'jon': p(k ='jo', a = 'non'),
'mon': p(k ='mo', a = 'mon') 
})

if not con:
    print( 'con = False ')
else:
    dic
    print('con = True')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ничего не понял

Answer (score 1):

Очень плохо сформулирован вопрос, но, проблема, судя по всему, в том, что у вас функции вызываются, когда вы пытаетесь указать их в качестве значения словаря.

Допустим, у вас есть функция, которая что-то печатает на экран:

```py
def func():
    print('Hello World!')
```

В данном случае `func` — будет ссылкой на функцию, а `func()` — ее непосредственным вызовом. То есть `func` вы можете передать как аргумент в другую функцию, чтобы позже вызвать (`func()`) ее там, например:

```py
def func():
    print('Hello World!')

def print_hello_world(function):
    function()
    
print_hello_world(func)
```

**Выхлоп:**

```py
Hello World!
```

Поэтому важно уметь отличать ссылку на функцию от ее вызова.

---

Вам, очевидно, в качестве значения словаря нужна именно ссылка на функцию. Но вы вместо этого просто вызываете ее.

По аналогии с предыдущим примером:

```py
my_dict = {'key': func()}
```

Здесь вы вызываете функцию, она печатает текст, но в качестве значения ключа `'key'` вы получите `None`, то есть `{'key': None}`, потому что функция `func` ничего не возвращает.

Если бы она была записана как-то так, то есть, возвращала бы результат:

```py
def func():
    return 'Hello World!'

my_dict = {'key': func()}
```

То в `my_dict` записался бы только результат работы функции, то есть `{'key': 'Hello World!'}`

---

Поэтому вам нужно указать именно ссылку на функцию:

```py
my_dict = {'key': func}
```

И тогда вы сможете обращаться к ней по ключу `'key'` и вызывать вот так:

```py
my_dict['key']()
```

---

Теперь перейдем к вашей функции `p`:

```py
def p(k , a):
    print (k,' ', a)
```

Ее запись и вызов с передачей аргументов будет выглядеть так:

```py
my_dict = {'key': p}
my_dict['key'](k ='jo', a = 'non')
```

Если вам нужно заранее задать аргументы прямо в словаре, то здесь стоит воспользоваться `lambda`-выражением:

```py
my_dict = {'key': lambda: p(k ='jo', a = 'non')}
my_dict['key']()
```

Результат будет тот же самый. Просто вы фактически оставите в словаре ссылку на функцию, которая при вызове, вызовет вашу функцию с передачей ей указанных параметров