# Как выполнить функцию discord.py через определенное время?

Tags: python, discord.py

Цель задачи - сделать систему мутов(именно чата, мут в войсе не нужен) в боте discord.py. Сам мут пользователю реализован через выдачу роли (права на роли отредактированы, чтобы юзер не мог писать в текстовых каналах). Так вот, выдать роль с мутом я могу, а как мне потом поменять роль юзеру через условные сутки?
Пытался задействовать Threading.Timer(), он не справился с этим, исполнил функцию не через n времени, а моментально. Какие есть еще идеи?
Пример кода:

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if a == a: #все условия для мута сходятся:
        await message.author.remove_roles(utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.UNMUTE_ROLE)) #удаляю роль everyone
        await message.author.add_roles(utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.MUTE_ROLE_HOUR)) #выдаю роль с мутом на час
        Timer(3600, await message.author.remove_roles(utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.MUTE_ROLE_HOUR))) #и тут через 3600 сек пытаюсь удалить роль мута у пользователя
        Timer(3600, await message.author.add_roles(utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.UNMUTE_ROLE))) #и вернуть роль everyone
```

Comment: Можете использовать функцию asyncio.sleep() для задержки времени выполнения функций.

Comment: А она не будет останавливать клиент целиком? Мне же надо чтобы бот дальше работал, он же не будет бездействовать и ждать истечения времени?

Comment: Проверил на asyncio.sleep(delay=5, result= await message.delete()), в result запихнул функцию удаления сообщения, просто для проверки работоспособности метода asyncio.sleep(), но задержки в 5 секунд не произошло, функция в result выполнилась моментально

Comment: @Turbo потому что вы путаете вызов функции со ссылкой на нее (недавно подробно разбирал различие в [другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1496344/373173))

Comment: @denisnumb Прочитал ваш разбор, я понимаю разницу ссылок и вызова функции. Но как это относится к моему вопросу? И, если будет не трудно, можете переписать эту часть кода, как она должна быть?

Comment: @Turbo в данном случае вы в качестве параметра `result` указываете не ссылку на метод удаления сообщения, а только передаете объект вызова удаления: `asyncio.sleep(delay=5, result= await message.delete())`. Поэтому сообщение удаляется сразу. Чтобы не заморачиваться со ссылкой на асинхронную функцию, проще вызвать ее в следующей строке, сразу после `await asyncio.sleep(5)`

Comment: @denisnumb Благодарю за разъяснение, буду пользоваться вашим способом. И чисто вопрос ради интереса, а ссылки на асинхронную функцию это долго, много и муторно?

Comment: @Turbo я, честно сказать, никогда такого не делал. Просто передать ссылку на асинхронную функцию можно без проблем. А вот засунуть вызов асинхронной функции внутрь `lambda` уже нельзя и это делается как-то костыльно, как по мне: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746213/how-to-use-await-in-a-python-lambda